# VBA Shell function fails to execute Python script

Tags: python, vba, excel, shell

I tried to execute Python script using the VBA code below (please run `sub Test()`),

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
     ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
     ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
     ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
     ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If

Const interpreter_path As String = "C:\Users\dongm\Anaconda2\python.exe"


Sub Test()
    RegressAndWait "Output"
End Sub

Private Sub RegressAndWait(ByVal output_folder_name As String)

    Dim TaskID As Long, hProc As Long, lExitCode As Long
    Dim ACCESS_TYPE As Integer, STILL_ACTIVE As Integer

    ACCESS_TYPE = &H400
    STILL_ACTIVE = &H103

    Dim Program As String, args(1 To 5) As String
    args(1) = interpreter_path
    args(2) = ThisWorkbook.path & "\regressions.py"
    args(3) = """" & "dummy" & """"
    args(4) = """" & "." & """"
    args(5) = """" & output_folder_name & """"
    Program = Join(args, " ")

    ChDir ThisWorkbook.path
    TaskID = Shell(Program, vbNormalFocus)
    hProc = OpenProcess(ACCESS_TYPE, False, TaskID)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot run regressions.py", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do
        GetExitCodeProcess hProc, lExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While lExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub
```

After running `sub Test()`, I can see the prompt window flashes and then exits as if the prompt window is opened but never used (I can't see if there is any message written to the prompt window since it disappears really fast).

However, I can run the python script manually without using VBA by opening `Anaconda Prompt` window, and then `cd` to my current folder address (why `ChDir ThisWorkbook.path`), and then enter `python regressions.py "dummy" "."` to the prompt window to run the python script.

My VBA code is basically just repeating what I have done manually, but why it doesn't work?

In addition, it's very strange that my code used to work well, but this morning I just found that it no longer works.

---

FYI, I stepped into `Program` using debugger before jumping into the `Shell` function, the `?Program` in the immediate window gives me

`C:\Users\dongm\Anaconda2\python.exe C:\Company\Insurance Project\Health Insurance Company Regression\regressions.py "dummy" "." "Output"`

---

After some manipulation, it seems that the reason that I am no longer able to call Python script is because I have folder that has space in its name. As I recalled, I moved the relevant files this morning to a different directory. I just changed `Insurance Project` to `Insurance_Project` and `Health Insurance Company Regression` to `Health_Insurance_Company_Regression`, then everything backs to normal. This is really an interesting bug, which I have never seen before, but I wonder what can cause this. Excel VBA or Python and Anaconda?

Comment: Nic I do not work with Py but based on what you said in the last line, I would double check what `Program` is evaluating to? `Program = Join(args, " ")` you may want to put a breakpoint there and check?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I edited my post based on your comment.

Comment: @SiddharthRout It looks like the reason is I cannot have folder whose name has space. As I recalled, I moved my relevant files to the folder `Insurance Project\Health Insurance Company Regression` today. Now I changed "Insurance Project" to "Insurance_Project" and "Health Insurance Company Regression" to "Health_Insurance_Company_Regression", then things started to work. But do you know if this is an issue caused by Excel VBA rather than my Python and Anaconda? I would like to exclude this possibility.

Comment: This is not a bug. You need to pad the spaces with double quotes. If you search stackoverflow, you will see lot of questions on this :) –